# Ajax sometimes working sometimes it doesn't

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

i really have problem with the ajax code that i have in my asp.net website. What the ajax is supposed to do is to retrieve the filename of the uploaded image through ajaxfileupload into the asp.net server. Unfortunately the outcome is, it will always give me an Object reference not set to an instance of an object in the asp.net code-behind because it doesn't return any value from the image that i uploaded using ajaxfileupload. And then after a bunch of tries, it will then suddenly work. And then after a couple of minutes, it will not work again. Its always this cycle where the code will work, then it will not and then it will work again. I don't really know if the problem is my ajax code or maybe the internet connection. Kindly help me guys on figuring this one out.

**Here is the code for the aspx(I have included all of my code but the main focus is only on the ajax script and the AjaxFileUpload which has the ID of itemFileUpload1 and itemFileUpload2):**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" 
CodeFile="CreateBrands.aspx.cs" Inherits="Pages_CreateBrands" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" 
TagPrefix="asp"%>  

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title>Music Store</title>
<script src="../Javascript/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function uploadComplete(sender, args) {
        var txt = document.getElementById("validatePicture");//Your 
              hiddenfield id
        txt.value = "1";

        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "Pages/CreateBrands.aspx",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (result1) {
                OnSuccess1(result1.d);
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                OnFailure1(error);
            }
        });
    }
    function OnSuccess1(result1) {
        var pp1 = document.getElementById("PicturePath1");
        pp1.value = result1;
    }
    function OnFailure1(error) {
        alert(error);
    }
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function uploadComplete2(sender, args) {
        var txt = document.getElementById("validatePicture2");//Your 
      hiddenfield id
        txt.value = "1";

        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "Pages/CreateBrands.aspx",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (result2) {
                OnSuccess1(result2.d);
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                OnFailure1(error);
            }
        });
    }
    function OnSuccess1(result2) {
        var pp2 = document.getElementById("PicturePath2");
        pp2.value = result2;
    }
    function OnFailure1(error) {
        alert(error);
    }
</script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Styles/jquery.bxslider.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Styles/StyleSheet.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Styles/font-awesome.min.css"/>
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="~/Images/rockSign.png"/>

<style type="text/css">
    .auto-style1 {
        width: 160px;
        height: 37px;
    }
    .auto-style2 {
        height: 37px;
    }
</style>



</head>
 <body>
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
          </asp:ScriptManager>
     <div id="wrapper">

        <header id="main_header">
            <div id="callout">
                <h2>&#9742; 111222333</h2>
                <p>Michigan State Kawasaki Iceland</p>
            </div>
            <h1>MUSIC STORE</h1>
        </header>

        <div class="clearfix"></div>

        <nav id="nav_menu">
            <ul id="nav">
                <li><a href="~/Pages/Home.aspx" runat="server">HOME</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">INSTRUMENTS</a>
                    <ul class="sub-menu">
                        <li><a href="~/Pages/GuitarBrands.aspx" 
     runat="server">ELECTRIC GUITARS</a></li>
                        <li><a href="~/Pages/BassBrands.aspx" 
     runat="server">BASS GUITARS</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">DRUMS</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">AMPLIFIERS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">ACCESSORIES</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">FEATURED ARTISTS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="../Images/cog.png" /></a>
                    <ul class="cog_submenu">
                        <li><a href="~/Pages/CreateBrands.aspx" 
    runat="server">CREATE NEW BRAND</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">USE EXISTING BRAND</a></li>
                        <li><a href="~/Pages/OverviewGuitarData.aspx" 
    runat="server">GUITAR DATA OVERVIEW</a></li>
                        <li><a href="~/Pages/OverviewBassData.aspx" 
    runat="server">BASS DATA OVERVIEW</a></li>
                    </ul>
               </li>
       </ul>
        </nav>

        <div id="content_area">

           <h3>&nbsp;</h3>
            <h3 class="headingTitle">Create New Brand(Step 1 of 2):</h3>

            <table cellspacing="15" class="brandsTable">

                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 160px; height: 37px;">

                    <strong>Brand Type:</strong></td>

                    <td style="height: 37px">

                        <asp:CheckBox ID="brandTypeGuitar" runat="server" 
    Text="Guitar" AutoPostBack="True" GroupName="brandType"/>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="brandTypeBass" runat="server" 
    Text="Bass" AutoPostBack="True" GroupName="brandType"/>

                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 160px; height: 37px;">

                    <strong>Brand Name:</strong></td>

                    <td style="height: 37px">

                    <asp:TextBox ID="brandName" runat="server" 
    BackColor="#FFFF66" BorderColor="Black" BorderWidth="1px" Height="20px" 
    Width="300px"></asp:TextBox>

                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td class="auto-style1">

                    <strong>Brand Image:</strong></td>

                    <td class="auto-style2">
                    <br/>
                    <asp:FileUpload ID="brandFileUpload" runat="server" />
                    <asp:Button ID="brandUploadImage" runat="server" 
    Text="Upload Image" OnClick="brandUploadImage_Click" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>

            <asp:Label ID="lblResult" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
            <br />
            <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" CssClass="submitButton" 
    Text="Save Brand" OnClick="btnSave_Click" />
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <h3 class="headingTitle">Create New Item(Step 2 of 2):</h3>
           <table cellspacing="15" class="brandsTable">

               <tr>
                    <td style="width: 160px; height: 37px;">

                    <strong>Item Type:</strong></td>

                    <td style="height: 37px">

                        <asp:RadioButton ID="itemType1" runat="server" 
    Text="Guitar" AutoPostBack="False" GroupName="itemType" 
    OnCheckedChanged="itemType1_CheckedChanged"/>
                        <asp:RadioButton ID="itemType2" runat="server" 
    Text="Bass" AutoPostBack="False" GroupName="itemType" 
    OnCheckedChanged="itemType1_CheckedChanged"/>

                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 160px; height: 37px;">

                    <strong>Item Brand:</strong></td>

                    <td style="height: 37px">

                    <asp:TextBox ID="itemBrand" runat="server" 
    BackColor="#FFFF66" BorderColor="Black" BorderWidth="1px" Height="20px" 
    Width="300px"></asp:TextBox>

                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 160px; height: 37px;">

                    <strong>Item Model:</strong></td>

                    <td style="height: 37px">

                    <asp:TextBox ID="itemModel" runat="server" 
    BackColor="#FFFF66" BorderColor="Black" BorderWidth="1px" Height="20px" 
    Width="300px"></asp:TextBox>

                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 160px; height: 37px;">

                    <strong>Item Price:</strong></td>

                    <td style="height: 37px">

                    <asp:TextBox ID="itemPrice" runat="server" 
     BackColor="#FFFF66" BorderColor="Black" BorderWidth="1px" Height="20px" 
     Width="300px"></asp:TextBox>

                    </td>
                </tr>



                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 160px; height: 37px;">

                    <strong>Item Image1:</strong></td>

                    <td style="height: 37px">

                    <br />

                      <asp:AjaxFileUpload ID="itemFileUpload1" runat="server" OnUploadComplete="itemUploadImage1_Click" OnClientUploadComplete="uploadComplete" MaximumNumberOfFiles="1"/>

                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 160px; height: 37px;">

                    <strong>Item Image2:</strong></td>

                    <td style="height: 37px">

                    <br />

                      <asp:AjaxFileUpload ID="itemFileUpload2" runat="server" OnUploadComplete="itemUploadImage2_Click" OnClientUploadComplete="uploadComplete2" MaximumNumberOfFiles="1"/>

                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 160px; height: 37px;">

                    <strong>Item Description:</strong></td>

                    <td style="height: 37px">

                    <asp:TextBox ID="itemDescription" runat="server" BackColor="#FFFF66" BorderColor="Black" BorderWidth="1px" Height="20px" Width="300px"></asp:TextBox>

                    </td>
                </tr>

               <tr>
                    <td style="width: 160px; height: 37px;">

                    <strong>Item Neck Type:</strong></td>

                    <td style="height: 37px">

                    <asp:TextBox ID="itemNeckType" runat="server" BackColor="#FFFF66" BorderColor="Black" BorderWidth="1px" Height="20px" Width="300px"></asp:TextBox>

                    </td>
                </tr>

               <tr>
                    <td style="width: 160px; height: 37px;">

                    <strong>Item Body:</strong></td>

                    <td style="height: 37px">

                    <asp:TextBox ID="itemBody" runat="server" BackColor="#FFFF66" BorderColor="Black" BorderWidth="1px" Height="20px" Width="300px"></asp:TextBox>

                    </td>
                </tr>

               <tr>
                    <td style="width: 160px; height: 37px;">

                    <strong>Item Fretboard:</strong></td>

                    <td style="height: 37px">

                    <asp:TextBox ID="itemFretboard" runat="server" BackColor="#FFFF66" BorderColor="Black" BorderWidth="1px" Height="20px" Width="300px"></asp:TextBox>

                    </td>
                </tr>

               <tr>
                    <td style="width: 160px; height: 37px;">

                    <strong>Item Fret:</strong></td>

                    <td style="height: 37px">

                    <asp:TextBox ID="itemFret" runat="server" BackColor="#FFFF66" BorderColor="Black" BorderWidth="1px" Height="20px" Width="300px"></asp:TextBox>

                    </td>
                </tr>

               <tr>
                    <td style="width: 160px; height: 37px;">

                    <strong>Item Bridge:</strong></td>

                    <td style="height: 37px">

                    <asp:TextBox ID="itemBridge" runat="server" BackColor="#FFFF66" BorderColor="Black" BorderWidth="1px" Height="20px" Width="300px"></asp:TextBox>

                    </td>
                </tr>

               <tr>
                    <td style="width: 160px; height: 37px;">

                    <strong>Item Neck Pickup:</strong></td>

                    <td style="height: 37px">

                    <asp:TextBox ID="itemNeckPickup" runat="server" BackColor="#FFFF66" BorderColor="Black" BorderWidth="1px" Height="20px" Width="300px"></asp:TextBox>

                    </td>
                </tr>

               <tr>
                    <td style="width: 160px; height: 37px;">

                    <strong>Item Bridge Pickup:</strong></td>

                    <td style="height: 37px">

                    <asp:TextBox ID="itemBridgePickup" runat="server" BackColor="#FFFF66" BorderColor="Black" BorderWidth="1px" Height="20px" Width="300px"></asp:TextBox>

                    </td>
                </tr>

               <tr>
                    <td style="width: 160px; height: 37px;">

                    <strong>Item Hardware Color:</strong></td>

                    <td style="height: 37px">

                    <asp:TextBox ID="itemHardwareColor" runat="server" BackColor="#FFFF66" BorderColor="Black" BorderWidth="1px" Height="20px" Width="300px"></asp:TextBox>

                    </td>
                </tr>

               </table>

               <asp:Label ID="lblResult2" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
               <br />

               <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" CssClass="submitButton" Text="Save Item" OnClick="Button1_Click"/>

        </div>


        <div class="clearfix"></div>

        <footer>
            <p>&copy;All Rights Reserved</p>
        </footer>


    </div>
 </form>
```

**Here is the code-behind(I also included every code in the code-behind but the main focus is only on the mehtod name ItemUploadImage1_Click, ItemUploadImage2_Click and Button1_Click. I would get the error in the Button1_Click and it will always point out the string item_image1 which is null):**

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using AjaxControlToolkit;

public partial class Pages_CreateBrands : System.Web.UI.Page
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

private void ClearTextFields()
{
    brandName.Text = "";
}

private void ClearTextFields2()
{
    itemBrand.Text = "";
    itemModel.Text = "";
    itemPrice.Text = "";
    itemDescription.Text = "";
    itemNeckType.Text = "";
    itemBody.Text = "";
    itemFretboard.Text = "";
    itemFret.Text = "";
    itemNeckPickup.Text = "";
    itemBridgePickup.Text = "";
    itemBridge.Text = "";
    itemHardwareColor.Text = "";
}

protected void brandUploadImage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    try
    {
        string filename = Path.GetFileName(brandFileUpload.FileName);
        brandFileUpload.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Images/Brands/") + 
       filename);
        lblResult2.Text = "Image " + filename + " successfully uploaded!";
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        lblResult.Text = "Upload failed!";
    }
 }

 protected void itemType1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    Session["itemType"] = (sender as RadioButton).Text;
 }


protected void itemUploadImage1_Click(object sender, AjaxFileUploadEventArgs 
 e)
{
    if (Session["itemType"] != null) {
        if (Session["itemType"].ToString() == "Guitar")
        {
            string filename = e.FileName;
            Session["PicturePath1"] = filename;
            itemFileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Images/Brands/String 
Instrument Items/Guitar/") + filename);
        }
        else if (Session["itemType"].ToString() == "Bass")
        {
            string filename = e.FileName;
            Session["PicturePath1"] = filename;
            itemFileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Images/Brands/String 
Instrument Items/Bass/") + filename);

        }
    }
}

protected void itemUploadImage2_Click(object sender, AjaxFileUploadEventArgs e)
{
    if (Session["itemType"] != null) {
        if (Session["itemType"].ToString() == "Guitar")
        {
            string filename = e.FileName;
            Session["PicturePath2"] = filename;
            itemFileUpload2.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Images/Brands/String Instrument Items/Guitar/") + filename);
        }
        else if (Session["itemType"].ToString() == "Bass")
        {
            string filename = e.FileName;
            Session["PicturePath2"] = filename;
            itemFileUpload2.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Images/Brands/String Instrument Items/Bass/") + filename);
        }
    }
}


protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (brandTypeGuitar.Checked && !brandTypeBass.Checked)
    {
        try
        {
            string brand_image = ConnectionClassBrands.brandFileName;
            string brand_name = brandName.Text;

            ConnectionClassBrands.AddBrandsForOneType(brandTypeGuitar.Text, brand_name, brand_image);
            lblResult.Text = "Upload successful!";

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            lblResult.Text = "Upload Failed!";
        }
    }
    else if (brandTypeBass.Checked && !brandTypeGuitar.Checked)
    {
        try
        {
            string brand_image = ConnectionClassBrands.brandFileName;
            string brand_name = brandName.Text;

            ConnectionClassBrands.AddBrandsForOneType(brandTypeBass.Text, brand_name, brand_image);
            lblResult.Text = "Upload successful!";

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            lblResult.Text = "Upload Failed!";
        }
    }
    else if (brandTypeGuitar.Checked && brandTypeBass.Checked)
    {
        try
        {
            string brand_image = ConnectionClassBrands.brandFileName;
            string brand_name = brandName.Text;

            ConnectionClassBrands.AddBrandsForTwoTypes(brandTypeGuitar.Text, brandTypeBass.Text, brand_name, brand_image);
            lblResult.Text = "Upload successful!";

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            lblResult.Text = "Upload Failed!";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        lblResult.Text = "Upload Failed!";
    }



    ClearTextFields();

}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

        if (itemType1.Checked)
        {

            int item_type = ConnectionClassBrands.GetIdByType(itemType1.Text);
            int item_brandId = ConnectionClassBrands.GetIdByBrand(itemBrand.Text);
            string item_model = itemModel.Text;
            double item_price = Convert.ToDouble(itemPrice.Text);
            string item_image1 = Session["PicturePath1"].ToString();
            string item_image2 = Session["PicturePath2"].ToString();
            string item_description = itemDescription.Text;
            string item_necktype = itemNeckType.Text;
            string item_body = itemBody.Text;
            string item_fretboard = itemFretboard.Text;
            string item_fret = itemFret.Text;
            string item_bridge = itemBridge.Text;
            string item_neckpickup = itemNeckPickup.Text;
            string item_bridgepickup = itemBridgePickup.Text;
            string item_hardwarecolor = itemHardwareColor.Text;


            ConnectionClassGuitarItems.AddStringInstrumentItems(item_type,item_brandId,item_model,item_price,item_image1,item_image2,
                item_description,item_necktype,item_body,item_fretboard,item_fret,item_bridge,item_neckpickup,
                item_bridgepickup,item_hardwarecolor);

            lblResult2.Text = "Upload successful!" + item_image1 + " and " + item_image2;




    }
        else if (itemType2.Checked)
        {
        try
        {
            int item_type = ConnectionClassBrands.GetIdByType(itemType2.Text);
            int item_brandId = ConnectionClassBrands.GetIdByBrand(itemBrand.Text);
            string item_model = itemModel.Text;
            double item_price = Convert.ToDouble(itemPrice.Text);
            string item_image1 = Session["PicturePath1"].ToString();
            string item_image2 = Session["PicturePath2"].ToString();
            string item_description = itemDescription.Text;
            string item_necktype = itemNeckType.Text;
            string item_body = itemBody.Text;
            string item_fretboard = itemFretboard.Text;
            string item_fret = itemFret.Text;
            string item_bridge = itemBridge.Text;
            string item_neckpickup = itemNeckPickup.Text;
            string item_bridgepickup = itemBridgePickup.Text;
            string item_hardwarecolor = itemHardwareColor.Text;


            ConnectionClassGuitarItems.AddStringInstrumentItems(item_type, item_brandId, item_model, item_price, item_image1, item_image2,
                item_description, item_necktype, item_body, item_fretboard, item_fret, item_bridge, item_neckpickup,
                item_bridgepickup, item_hardwarecolor);

            lblResult2.Text = "Upload successful!";

            ClearTextFields2();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            lblResult2.Text = ex.Message;
        }


    }

  }




 }
```

Here is the stack trace error:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the 
current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information 
about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set 
to an instance of an object.

Source Error: 


Line 168:                string item_model = itemModel.Text;
Line 169:                double item_price = 
Convert.ToDouble(itemPrice.Text);
Line 170:                string item_image1 = 
Session["PicturePath1"].ToString();
Line 171:                string item_image2 = 
Session["PicturePath2"].ToString();
Line 172:                string item_description = itemDescription.Text;

Source File: c:\Users\User1\Documents\Visual Studio 
2015\WebSites\MusicStore\Pages\CreateBrands.aspx.cs    Line: 170 

Stack Trace: 


[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an 
object.]
Pages_CreateBrands.Button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in 
c:\Users\User1\Documents\Visual Studio 
2015\WebSites\MusicStore\Pages\CreateBrands.aspx.cs:170
System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +9696694
System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) 
+204


System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler
.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +12
System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, 
String eventArgument) +15
System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +35
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, 
Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1639
```

Comment: Do you think, we really need a whole source code of a complete portal??

Comment: is there code for `Pages/CreateBrands.aspx`? because that's where you post

Comment: Who would waste time reading on an entire source code.

Post the exact part not the whole codebase

Comment: @Merigold - i thought its best to post the whole code to better find the origin of the problem. Anyway, i've added a description on parts of the code that is needed.

Comment: Your exception handling is very poor. Your are catching every possible exception and simply printing `"Upload Failed!"`. That suppresses useful error information. Catch a more specific kind of exception or do not catch at all.

Comment: @JaromandaX - the code for the CreateBrands.aspx is the aspx code that i have provided above. Is the url correct? I'm a total beginner in using ajax. But if its wrong, how come sometimes it is working?

Comment: @AluanHaddad - i will include the stack trace error in my question above.

Comment: @BoomClick that is not what I mean. I mean don't be so quick to catch.

Comment: @AluanHaddad - oh sorry. But I have already included the stack trace so feel free to look the error. By the way this error comes and goes. Sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't. Really weird problem.

Comment: Pages/CreateBrands.aspx is wrong it should be  CreateBrands.aspx/Pages.Also I cannot see any pages method in your .cs page

Comment: The problem is obviously that value of `Session["PicturePath1"]` is null, it's not problem with ajax calls, it's problem of whenever you set the value to session or not, or whenever you replace it with null later.

Comment: @Uphar - even if i change the url, its still getting the error.

Comment: @CrudaLilium - then how come sometimes its working??

Comment: @BoomClick You probably invoke itemUploadImage1_Click which sets value different from null to your `Session["PicturePath1"]` and later invoke it again and sets null to it, or you change the value of it in completely different place, or you lose your session.

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues in your code :

```
 1. Ajax Url : 
    url: "Pages/CreateBrands.aspx" // Worng
    Correct Url : "CreateBrands.aspx/Pages"

    //Also ensure that Pages method must be there in your CreateBrands.aspx.cs page.

    2. You files name is coming null
     string filename = e.FileName;

    //Check if e.filename is null or not before setting it into the Session Variable.

    //If it is null then you can try using normal asp:FileUpload 
    and through jquery you can make the ajax call with help of fileUpload id. 

    $('#itemFileUpload1').click(function() {..Your ajax call inside..});

    3. Also you are using the 

    Session["PicturePath1"] //which is fine 

    //but in your aspx page you are accessing it like 

    document.getElementById("PicturePath1"); 

    //This is wrong you cannot access Session variable like this .You can 
    directly use your session variable in aspx page like:

    "<%=Session["PicturePath1"]%>".
```

Try making these changes and check if it works or not 
Thanks!!

Comment: I tried number 3 and implemented it in my code like this -> function OnSuccess1(result1) {
            var pp1 =   "<%=Session["PicturePath1"]%>";
            pp1.value = result1;
        }. But how come its giving me an error that says "the controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks". Can you please elaborate on where to place the code blocks?

Comment: I have also tried number 2. And it seems like the e.filename is not null. What i did was in order to know if its null, i placed a code where if its null, it would redirect in a different page. But since it did not redirect in a different page, it means that the e.filename is not null. It will always be null in the item_image1, which is located in the Button1_Click method.

Comment: As for number 1, i have added the method for Pages.

Comment: for number 3 point  var pp1 = "<%=Session["PicturePath1"]%>"; pp1.value = result1; this is wrong , only this var pp1 = "<%=Session["PicturePath1"]%>" will give you the value of session and you cannot do like pp1.value, If you want to change the Session value then  <%Session["PicturePath1"] =result1;%>

Comment: for point 2 as per your stack trace line 170 is giving null refference error which is string item_image1 = 
Session["PicturePath1"].ToString(); so it mean your session variable value is null and it can only be null when your e.Filename is null assuming itemUploadImage1_Click is getting called and Session["itemType"] is not null and either contains Guitar or Bass

Comment: I'm still having the exception error the controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks.

Comment: this null reference error is making me go crazy. I've placed every if else statement in my code to detect if something is null but it always get through and will have the same error. I wonder if the problem is the ajax toolkit that i have downloaded. I mean, if i just use a regular fileupload, everything will be okay. It just so happens that i wanted to really to try and make this ajax fileupload work.

Comment: Have you checked Session["PicturePath1"] value?

Comment: yes, it is not null as well. But i have noticed that sometimes i think the javascript code is not working. Because i have added an if else statement in function OnSuccess1, that if pp is equals to null, it will send an alert. It did not. And then i tried messing around the ajax code to intentionally make the alert to pop up, but it also did not show up. Which gave me this doubt that maybe my javascript code is really not working after all. What are your thoughts on this?